# Show Riemann-integrability of $h:=\max\{f,g\}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification

> Let be $f,g$ two Riemann-integrable functions on the interval $[a,b]$ where $a<b$. Show that $h:=\max\{f,g\}$ is also Riemann-integrable on $[a,b]$.

---

**My approach:**

First, a bit of notation:

\begin{align*}
&M_i^h:=\sup\{\max\{f(x),g(x)\}\mid x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]\}\\ 
&m_i^h:=\inf\{\max\{f(x),g(x)\}\mid x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]\}\\  
&M_i^f:=\inf\{f(x)\mid x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]\}\\
&m_i^f:=\inf\{f(x)\mid x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]\}\text{ and }g \text{ analogously.}
\end{align*}

Then, we recall the upper and lower Darboux sums of $h$, where $P=(t_0,\cdots,t_n)$ is a partition of $[a,b]$:
\begin{align*}
&U(h,P):=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nM_i^h(t_i-t_{i-1})\\
&L(h,P):=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nm_i^h(t_i-t_{i-1}).
\end{align*}
As $f$ and $g$ are Riemann-integrable we know that for a given $\frac{\epsilon}{2}>0$ there exists a partition $P^*$ of $[a,b]$ such that for all partitions $P$ which have a higher refinement, it follows
$$
U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\text{ and } U(g,P)-L(g,P)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.
$$
If $M_i^h-m_i^h$ attains the form $M_i^f-m_i^g$, then it holds $0\leq M_i^f-m_i^g\leq M_i^f-m_i^f$.

If $M_i^h-m_i^h$ attains the form  $M_i^g-m_i^f$, then it holds $0\leq M_i^g-m_i^f\leq M_i^g-m_i^g$.

Now, we immediately see that
\begin{align*}
&0\leq U(h,P)-L(h,P)\\
&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(M_i^h-m_i^h)(t_i-t_{i-1})\leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^n(M_i^f-m_i^f)(t_i-t_{i-1})+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(M_i^g-m_i^g)(t_i-t_{i-1})\\
&=U(f,P)-L(f,P)+U(g,P)-L(g,P)<\epsilon.
\end{align*}
This holds for any finer Partition of $P$, so $h$ is Riemann-integrable.

As an aside, we know that Riemann-integrability of $f$ implies Riemann-integrability of $c\cdot f$, where $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Hence, $-\max\{-f(x),-g(x)\}=\min\{f(x),g(x)\}$ is also Riemann-integrable.

---

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Yes, seems correct to me.

Comment: Maybe using the fact that $h = \frac{f + g + |f - g|}{2}$ you could find a neater proof.